# How to Print Dictionary Data from array in array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, xcode7.3

How Can I Print ActivityName & Description?

I have this type of scenario in response I need to parse this data and Print ActivityId,ActivityName & Description.

```
 Project List Array Activites List:= Array
 (
   (
     { 
        ActivityID = 4;
        ActivityName = Development;
        Description = Development;
        IsActive = 1;
      },
     ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two for each loop

Let `projectListArray` be your first array, `projectList` be each array inside it and `projectDict` be each dictionary inside it.

```
for (NSArray *projectList in projectListArray) {
    for (NSDictionary *projectDict in projectList) {
       NSLog(@"Activity ID = %d",[projectDict objectForKey:@"ActivityID"]);
       NSLog(@"Activity Name = %d",[projectDict objectForKey:@"ActivityName"]);
       NSLog(@"Description = %d",[projectDict objectForKey:@"Description"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First getting Plist to array

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yourPlistName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *arrPlist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:stringPath];
```

Then get data from array

```
for(int i=0;i<arrPlist.count;i++)
{
  NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormmat:@"%@",[arrPlist objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ActivityID"]];
  NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormmat:@"%@",[arrPlist objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ActivityName"]];
  NSString *strDesc = [NSString stringWithFormmat:@"%@",[arrPlist objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Description"]];
}
```